# Cannot assign view permission for GA360 to Google Groups

Tags: google-analytics, permissions, google-iam

When assigning permission to Google Groups, an error "Failed to register users" shows up. Not sure what is wrong behind the scene.

As we do want to centralize our user management using solely Google Identity (https://groups.google.com/). Is there a way to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you are using GA360 (paid version), you should reach out to your GA360 support contact

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is that the email address needs to be either a **google business account**, or a **@gmail.com** address.

Quite frustrating that google doesn't tell you this in the error message, and they've closed any threads when people ask on their forms, but hopefully this saves people a few minutes / hours / days of googling.

Comment: Is there any work around for this? Our org has hundreds of staff who want access to GA, but none of them have Google accounts (they have MS accounts). If we asked them all to go off and setup private google accounts it would be a security and maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I would assume they would need to be made into google business accounts, which start around $5/mo/user